# How to generate REST API Documentation using enunciate through ANT Build Tool?

Tags: ant, build, enunciate

My first assignment at work is to do an enunciate build to generate Rest API Documentation. I am using Ant Build Tool. I am applying enunciate on one of our modules called xmbo. I am encountering an error:

> java.util.zip.ZipException: ZIP file must have at least one entry during the build process.

I have defined the following classpath for enunciate task as per http://enunciate.codehaus.org/executables.html#ant (I have commented out spring module in the below code as it is optional)

```
<path id="enunciate.base.classpath">
  <fileset dir="${enunciate.home}/lib">    
    <include name="*.jar"/>
    <exclude name="enunciate-jersey-1.28.jars"/>
    <exclude name="enunciate-jersey-rt-1.28.jar"/>
    <exclude name="enunciate-xml-1.28.jar"/>
    <exclude name="enunciate-java-client-1.28.jar"/>
    <exclude name="enunciate-jaxws-ri-1.28.jar"/>
    <exclude name="enunciate-jaxws-support-1.28.jar"/>
    <exclude name="enunciate-jaxws-support-1.28.jar"/>
   </fileset>

     <!--include (optional) spring module-->
    <!--<fileset dir="${enunciate.home}/lib/modules/spring">-->
      <!--<include name="*.jar"/>-->
    <!--</fileset>-->
</path>
```

Enunciate Target:

```
<taskdef name="enunciate" classname="org.codehaus.enunciate.main.EnunciateTask"> 
   <classpath refid="enunciate.base.classpath"/> 
</taskdef> 

<target name="generate_api_doc" depends="compile_xmbo"> 
  <delete dir="${enunciate.src.dir}"/> 
  <mkdir dir="${enunciate.src.dir}"/> 
  <delete dir="${xmbo.build.dir}/stage/xmbo/webservices/war/docs"/> 
  <mkdir dir="${xmbo.build.dir}/stage/xmbo/webservices/war/docs"/> 
   <copy todir="${enunciate.src.dir}"> 
     <fileset dir="${xmbo.src.dir}"> 
       <include name="com/../webservice/**"/> 
       <include name="com/../wso/**"/> 
       <include name="com/../constants/**"/> 
       <exclude name="com/../**"/> 
       <exclude name="com/../**"/> 
     </fileset> 
   </copy> 

 <enunciate basedir="${enunciate.src.dir}" configFile="${config.dir}/properties/enunciate.xml"> 

    <include name="**/*.java"/> 
    <exclude name="**/client/**,**/xdm/**"/> 
    <classpath refid="enunciate.full.classpath"/> 

    <export artifactId="docs" destination="${xmbo.build.dir}/stage/xmbo/webservices/war/docs"/> 
    <javacArgument argument="-g"/> 
  </enunciate> 
 </target>
```

(include and exclude under the copy task, I haven't given the complete names in this page but in my xml file it is correct). 
The target generate_api_doc depeneds on the target compile_xmbo which compiles and creates the required jars to be "enunciated".

Enunciate.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <enunciate>
    <api-classes>
  <exclude pattern="**/xdm/**/*.java"/>
  <exclude pattern="com.xactly.xdm.*"/>
  <exclude pattern="com.xactly.xbpm.****"/>
    </api-classes>
    <deployment protocol="http" host="http://.../xmbo/xmbows" context="/api"/>
    <webapp doCompile="false" doLibCopy="false"/>
  </enunciate>
```

(Host is our server address)

Once I run the build by calling the module target deploy_api_doc through command line, it gives java.util.zip.ZipException: ZIP file must have at least one entry.

Am I doing anything wrong?